# How to best optimize queries searching for free form varchar strings in Oracle 11.2?

Tags: indexing, oracle11g, operators, varchar, freeform

First, I'm currently using:

Oracle SQL Developer Version 17.2.0.188 
Oracle Database 11g 11.2.0.40.0

I have some important values a description column that are entered free-form.
While there are probably 30 descriptions, these are entered in hundreds of different ways without much consistency.
Example: 
Description: chevrolet,Chevrolet, chevrolet1, chevRolet40
My first suggestion was to just make a validation list to be chosen upon input to avoid querying 
UPPER(Description) Like '%DESCRIPTION%' but I'm looking for other options.

Comment: I would say you are right, if there are only about 30 sensible values then they should be selected from a list, not typed in.  In fact the description should not be stored in this table at all, rather a reference or code should be, which can then be joined to a look-up table to get the description.  That's basic normalisation!

Comment: Agreed. Just scouting out other options because I do not think that change will be enforced.